# How to create a service with administrator rights from c++ code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, registry

I have created a bat to execute script file(.vbs) to get installed software list from windows registry.
I following 2 way to execute the bat file.

1) execute the bat file from command prompt(cmd).
2) Create a service to execute bat file.(I have created a process).

two outputs are different.

I think registry access is restricted to service. So how to create a service or start a service as administrator like cmd as administrator.

Comment: A service usually runs under the LOCAL SYSTEM account, that may have another set of applications installed from the administrator account. Besides, querying the registry is the wrong approach to ask the system for installed applications.

Comment: Your problem diagnosis is wrong. Step 1, diagnose the problem correctly. Step 2, think about possible solutions. You need to get step 1 right before proceeding.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. If you use `nullptr` as the argument for `lpServiceStartName` then it will run as an administrator.

Comment: From [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682450.aspx): *"lpServiceStartName: If this parameter is NULL, CreateService uses the [LocalSystem account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684190.aspx)."* This is **not** the administrator account. I have no idea why anyone would upvote a factually incorrect answer.

Comment: @IInspectable i didn't say the administrator account. It has administrator privileges.

Comment: *"it will run as an administrator"* - and that is incorrect. It will runs as LOCAL SYSTEM, as documented. This is a different environment from an administrator's environment.